# jquery return error 400 when POSTing large data to wcf web service

Tags: jquery, asp.net, wcf, service, web

I call my WCF Web service using JQuery .AJAX and pass a collection of items to process.  The majority of the time it works fine, but when I have a large number of items in the collection when I POST I immediately get an Error 400.

Here is the jQuery code :

```
   //  Get the selected items
    var oAssayOrderListSelected = jQuery.grep(oAssayOrderList, function (element, index) {
        return element.SelectedForProcessing == true;
    });

    DataAsJson = { "SelectedItems": oAssayOrderListSelected };
    var DataAsJsonString = JSON.stringify(DataAsJson);

    //  Call the web service to Process the Assays
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: "AssayControlWS.svc/ProcessOrdersForAssays",
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        dataType: "json",
        data: DataAsJsonString,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (processingResults) {
            //  Update the results table with the result information
            if (processingResults.Status == "Success") {
            }
            else {
                // insert error message handler!!!!!
            }
        },
```

Here is the declaration of the web service method being called:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public ReleaseResult ProcessOrdersForAssays(List<AssayGroupOrOrderSummary> SelectedItems)
    {    ... }
```

Here is the web.config entries for the service. As it shows I have increased the buffer sizes greatly from the defaults

```
           <service name="AssayControl_Web.AssayControlWS" behaviorConfiguration="metadataAndDebug">
            <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="AssayControl_Web.AssayControlWSAspNetAjaxBehavior"
                binding="webHttpBinding" contract="AssayControl_Web.AssayControlWS" bindingName="AssayControl_Web.AssayControlWS" />
        </service>

<behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="metadataAndDebug">
            <serviceMetadata  httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl=""/>
              <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          </behavior>
       </serviceBehaviors>
    </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>


<webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="AssayControl_Web.AssayControlWS" maxBufferSize="200000000"
                maxBufferPoolSize="200000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="200000000"
                transferMode="Buffered" />
</webHttpBinding>
```

Any thoughts on what is causing this 400 error?

===================   Problem solved    ===============================

After adding WCF logging I was able to see that the issue was that the web service was using the default value of 65536 for the maxReceivedMessageSize.  This was in spite of my setting this value to a much higher value.

Additionally searching showed that several other people had encountered the issue of the maxReceivedMessageSize being ignored.  The way I fixed the problem was to remove the Name property from the webHttpBinding, making that setting the default for all webHttpBinding.  Then remove the BindingName property from service Endpoint so it used the default binding.

Here is a link to other reports of this problem with the same fix, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/985e039f-1610-4f62-9c3d-51ec7e1b1673/problem-with-maxreceivedmessagesize-webconfig-ignored. Perhaps this has something to do with the new simplified binding methods used with .net 4.0 and later.

Comment: What is the exception you get? and which .NET framework version are you using?

Comment: Can you show us your client config?

Comment: I am using .net 4.0.  No exception on the client, just the 400 error.

Comment: The since the WS is in the same project as the one that contains the .js file that calls the WS there is not WS reference entry for the client side.  The client side structure is index.htm which contains index.js which has the .ajax call.

Comment: you are getting an http 400 error because there is an exception from the server when calling the wcf service. Lookup wcf logging to find the exception. Also, can you please show your full config? what about behaviorConfiguration?

Comment: Thanks PostureOfLearning.  I added the behavior information and will enable wcf logging.

Comment: Thanks PostureOfLearning.  The key to seeing what was happening was to enable wcf logging.  To fix the issue I had to make the binding default.  The name based lookup appears to be ignored.  See text for my "fix".